# Termite Damage or Dirt?

Tags: termite

Is this termite damage? There's diagonal tan steak on the wood. When I tap the stud with a screw driver it feels solid. I don't see any tubes. Is it termite mud or simply dirt? How do I tell? [image]

Comment: That streak on the wood...Do you have a tall dog?    I'd take a hammer and your screw driver and drive it in the stud about 1" in 3-4 places. If it's solid, I'd keep you dog outside.

Comment: Doesn't look like any termite damage I have ever seen.

Comment: I contacted my pest control company. It wasn't termites-- simply construction dirt from 50 yrs ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted my pest control company. It wasn't termites-- simply construction dirt from 50 yrs ago. –